# How to select 2 specific people from a 10 people group

Tags: conditional-probability

I have this problem to solve

There are ten people in a class. Ari and Jamaal are twins in this class.  At random, two people will be chosen as the class representatives. What  are the odds that Ari and Jamaal will both be chosen?

I can guess the solution

For the first pick, there is a 2 out of 10 probability. For the second  pick, there is a 1 out of 9 probability. Therefore, 20% * 11% = 2.2%.
However I am not understanding the logic

can someone help ??

Comment: Your "guess" looks reasonable.  In what sense do you think your method is not logical?

Answer (score 2):

You might see the logic with conditional probability statements:

$A_1$ is the event Ari is selected in the first pick.  $A_2$ for the second

$J_1$ is the event Jamal is selected in the first pick. $J_2$ for the second

$P(A_1) = P(J_1) = 1/10$

$P(A_2 | \bar{A_1}) = P(J_2 | \bar{J_1}) = 1/9$

$P([A_1 \cap J_2] \cup [J_1 \cap A_2]) = P(A_1)P(J_2|A_1) + P(J_1)P(A_2|J_1) - P([A_1 \cap J_2] \cap [J_1 \cap A_2]) = (1/10)(1/9) + (1/10)(1/9) + 0 = 2/90$

Answer (score 0):

Simulation gives us ~2.2%.

You could simulate to check your answer in `R`:

```
people <- c("A","J",1:8) # let A = Ari and J = Jamaal

nsim <- 100000
count <- rep(NA,nsim)


for (i in 1:nsim){
  
  x1 <- sample(people,1,replace = F)
  x2 <- sample(people[-which(people==x1)],1,replace = F)
  
  if (sum(c(x1,x2) == c("A","J")) == 2 | sum(c(x1,x2) == c("J","A")) == 2){ count[i] = 1}
    else count[i] = 0
  

  
  
}

sum(count)/nsim*100
```